# How to list restricted folders on Mac OS with Java?

Tags: java, bash, macos, privileges

I'm trying to run this snippet:

```java
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        var home = System.getProperty("user.home");
        var location = home + "/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup";
        var pb = new ProcessBuilder("ls", "-al", location);
        var p = pb.start();
        System.out.println(p.waitFor());
        IOUtils.copy(p.getInputStream(), System.out);
        IOUtils.copy(p.getErrorStream(), System.err);
    }

}
```

It should list a folder where iPhone's backups are stored. I'm getting the following output:

```bash
1 # exit code
total 0
ls: /Users/zjor/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup: Operation not permitted
```

However, if I run the following command in the terminal under the same user it works well:

```bash
ls -al "/Users/zjor/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup"
total 0
drwxr-xr-x    3 zjor  staff    96 Oct 23 15:01 .
drwxr-xr-x    3 zjor  staff    96 Jan 17  2023 ..
drwxr-xr-x@ 262 zjor  staff  8384 Oct 23 14:55 00003101-123456780CC3XXXX
```

As far as I understand, the app should request special permissions to access some folders. But how to do it?

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Why would you run `ls` as a subprocess and need to interpret its stderr to get the details of what went wrong in presence of a nonzero exit status, rather than try to perform the filesystem operation direct from the JVM and get an exception to inform you of the same failure?

Comment: Anyhow -- do you really need the app  to make the request itself, or will instructions to grant the access from System Settings do for your purposes?

Answer (score 0):

to access restricted folders on Mac OS, you can also use the `Files` class from the `java.nio.file` package and you can use `Files.list()` method to list the contents of the specified directory,so if the directory is restricted, it will throw an `IOException`!

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        var home = System.getProperty("user.home");
        var location = home + "/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup";
        var path = Paths.get(location);

        try {
            Files.list(path)
                    .forEach(System.out::println);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP doesn't need administrator privileges -- just the user's regular permissions to the directory at hand.

Comment: thnx @CharlesDuffy, while administrator privileges are not necessary in this case, the user still needs to grant the necessary permissions for the application to access the restricted folder, it can be done by using the `osascript` command and the `do shell script` option with the appropriate permissions!

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Freeman, but I still get an error:

```
0:86: execution error: ls: /Users/zjor/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup: Operation not permitted (1)
```

does your snippet above work for you?

Comment: @zjor so you can use the `Files` class from the `java.nio.file` package, I will update my answer !

Comment: @Freeman thanks for your updates. But still getting an error:

java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /Users/zjor/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup: Operation not permitted
 at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:100)

I have Mac OS: Sonoma 14

Comment: @Freeman I even tried to invoke a python scripts with performs "ls" command on that folder, if called in the terminal it works well, but when called from Java, I get "Operation not permitted". Looks like Java itself should request a permission to access certain folders.

Answer (score 0):

So far, I ended up opening `System Settings > Privacy & Security > Full Disk Access` dialog and adding my IDE or a bundled app there.
The snippet below shows how to open the dialog:

```java
...
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(URI.create("x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_AllFiles"));
...
```